# MulticellRNN Error with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I have Tensorflow 1.1.0

And am following a basic tutorial from https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/14_recurrent_neural_networks.ipynb on Multicell (stacked) RNNs

The following code generates an odd error and I can't figure out why from searching.

```
import tensorflow as tf
n_inputs = 2
n_neurons = 100
n_layers = 3
n_steps = 5

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs])
basic_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=n_neurons)
multi_layer_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([basic_cell for _ in range(n_layers)])
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multi_layer_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

This seems to be the correct code but it gets the error:

ValueError: Attempt to reuse RNNCell  with a different variable scope than its first use.  First use of cell was with scope 'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_rnn_cell', this attempt is with scope 'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/basic_rnn_cell'.  Please create a new instance of the cell if you would like it to use a different set of weights.  **If before you were using: MultiRNNCell([BasicRNNCell(...)] * num_layers), change to: MultiRNNCell([BasicRNNCell(...) for _ in range(num_layers)]).**  If before you were using the same cell instance as both the forward and reverse cell of a bidirectional RNN, simply create two instances (one for forward, one for reverse).  In May 2017, we will start transitioning this cell's behavior to use existing stored weights, if any, when it is called with scope=None (which can lead to silent model degradation, so this error will remain until then.)

I bolded a part that I made the switch to from the code in the Github.
Any idea on why this is still throwing an error?
Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line of code:

```
multi_layer_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([basic_cell for _ in range(n_layers)])
```

The basic_cell variable needs to be replaced with a function. When you use a variable, each layer of the n_layers network will be using the same set of weights. Instead, trying to use a function:

```
def create_rnn_layer(n_neurons):
    return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=n_neurons)
```

Then replace basic_cell with create_rnn_layer(n_neurons). This way, when the network is created. The function will be called n_layers of times, hence will be using different weights.